# Grafana tempo: multi tenant setup

Tags: grafana-tempo

I am reading [this](https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/operations/multitenancy/) to understand multi-tenancy in grafana tempo.

So what I understand is that enabling multi-tenancy ensures that when a trace is pushed to be stored in tempo backend, it has all the multi tenant ids with it.

So suppose a request travelled from department A to departmnet B and then to department C. So when trace for such a request is pushed to tempo backend, it would have all three tenant ids(embedded in their correspnding spans) with it.

Also, I understand currently in open-source tempo(not the enterprise one), when we search for a tenant id in a multi-tenant setup, it fetches only those spans having that tenant id. So in aove example if i search for B, then spans for other tenant ids(A,C) wont be fetched.

Is this correct understanding of multi-tenant setup in grafana tempo?